# Why was my NAA flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, accepted-answer, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4611582/2476755) as not an answer, but my flag was declined:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I was under the impression that link-only answers should be flagged as NAA. Why was my flag declined?

For future reference, here is a screenshot of the answer:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: The NAA flag is reserved for strictly obvious non-answers; things like "Hey, I want some help with foo" or "I have this problem too".  Eg, answers  which look nothing like answers, judging them from a perspective of not being able to see the question..  mainly because mods _can't_ see the question when reviewing this type of flag.   See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224452/184887) for more details.

Comment: @Daedalus see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers); also, the LQ posts queue definitely allows for the deletion of link-only answers: `“While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”`

Comment: Not my point.  If it looks like an answer, the NAA flag does not apply, simple as that.

Comment: It does *not* look like an answer; it looks like a conglomeration of links. It does not answer any question and should have instead been a comment.

Comment: To you, it doesn't look like an answer; to the mod, it does; and as shown in the post I linked, NAA flags are evaluated on the answer itself, without the context of the question; even if it's a poor attempt at an answer, it was an attempt, and that's what matters for the NAA flag.

Comment: @Daedalus http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer#comment739868_226142 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144581/259818

Comment: For that particular answer, displayed in a screen shot of the question in which the comment you linked took place... there is indeed, absolutely zero information in the answer.  However, for the answer you link in this question, there is something of detail, even if it isn't much.  Its certainly better than the one linked in that question.  While I agree, there is little to no information in that 'answer', it still looks enough like an answer to disqualify use of the NAA flag.  In the light which you are arguing, I almost believe there should be a 'link only answer' flag.

Comment: @Daedalus if there is "little to no information" (little is being conservative; there is in fact absolutely zero useful stand-alone information in the answer), how is the use of a NAA flag disqualified?

Comment: Because, if it looks like an answer, and/or is an attempt at an answer, the NAA flag does not apply.  As linked in my first comment to you, the NAA flag is about strictly obvious non-answers; if there is any tinge of doubt, it shouldn't be used, and that means more than your doubt, but the doubt of someone reviewing the flag.  I'm sure I don't need to reiterate the points that were given as the answer in the first linked post.  FWIW, if I could cast a delete vote, I would.

Comment: @Daedalus My point is that the answer is really nothing more than gibberish. How does "Here is an article" and "Here is a link to a lecture" answer the question? If the answer were "You should write a recursive method that prints the left side of the tree, then the node, then the right side" before providing the two links, it would qualify as an answer. [clarification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/259818): answers can be mostly links, provided they say something about the links (i.e., the example I just gave).

Comment: Lets just agree to disagree; it's obvious at this point I'm not going to convince you otherwise.

Comment: Well, given the upvotes on your question, and the downvotes on my answer, and the upvotes on Braiam's answer - I completely have no idea how the NAA flag works anymore! Or, more accurately, how others think it works.

Comment: @James if only we could hear from the mod who dealt with this flag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> This article discusses multiple approaches to serializing a binary tree. In addition, here is a spring 2009 lecture (web archive) given at the University of California, San Francisco by Dr. David Galles.

And the question is "How to Serialize Binary Tree?", so yeah, that's not an answer, as the plain text doesn't contain even *a bit* of information answering the question. I normally see that moderators seldom of removing an accepted answer, but in this case, I don't see why they wouldn't, considering that there's a [complete operative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422820/792066) that addresses the concerns of the question, I think substantially, so there isn't any lost value over deleting that answer.

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted since it seems to be the majority view.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some [search results](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=why+was+my+naa+flag+declined) about "why my naa flag was declined".  In addition, [here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h5cY7d6nPU) given by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: Now I have no idea whether I should up- or down-vote. Damn shame I don't have a sock to do both ;-)

Comment: Could I flag this as NAA?

Comment: @wewesthemenace: On the main site, sure you could. On meta, this one is actually in a gray area and probably *just* on the right side of acceptable, as long as it's done in moderation. And does not relegate the actual answers to obscurity.

Comment: @wewesthemenace this post serves to show the (f)utility of the 'answer' on the main site. That *this* isn't useful (intentionally so) means that the main site post isn't useful either. If one is tempted to NAA this post, I would encourage them to down vote the main site post. As NAA flags on it have been declined, this would allow 20k users to then vote to delete the answer when it goes negative. It is unfortunate that this is the case - for those who care about internet points or preserving them on old posts, if it was deleted by a mod initially those points would have been grandfathered in.

Comment: @MichaelT the answer is now negative, so 20k-rep users can vote to delete

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that the NAA flag is correct here.

If the links are dead, then there is no information that can be used to solve the problem.  That is, with the absence of the links, the answer is worthless.

If I need a way to serialize binary trees, and all I have is that answer--nothing else, no links--then I'm no closer to a solution than I was before I read the answer.  Not the slightest bit closer.

**Edit 1:**

As it stands, the answer is no more useful than a Google search, even with the links.

That being said, rather than flagging the question, a better option might have been to visit at least one of the links and quote part of the page.

**Edit 2:**

Hey, look, that USFCA link is on the first page for a `serializing binary trees` Google search.  What a coincidence!  I'm willing to bet the first link was, too, before it died.

Comment: If there's an actual answer too, there's no need to write one yourself, and especially not in someone else's name. Aside from that...

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, if they were valuable, hard-to-find links, it might be worth the effort; however, since they're just from Google, I'd have to agree.