# Historical Joke/XKCD Answer in Low Quality Posts Review Queue

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, specific-answer

I recently ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421142/2415822) in the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9093267)

It indeed does not answer the question, but I'm afraid to mark it as such since it:

1. has 25 upvotes and could be an audit.
2. was written in 2009 before most of the rules that we have today.
3. is a historical XKCD answer, and while not completely on-topic it is relevant.

What is the appropriate action for old posts like this?

Comment: Why does any of that matter? If you don't think it answers the question, then that's the only thing that really matters.

Comment: Not an answer. The poster could have included it in their other answer on the same page but even then it is of dubious relevance to the question asked as it is just a joke name.

Comment: Should normally be posted as a comment.  But completely off topic here, no sign of a SQL injection problem anywhere.  Zap it.

Comment: Not an audit BTW I've voted "recommend deletion".

Comment: Here's another candidate (same post): http://stackoverflow.com/a/421190/1842065

Comment: Both posts are gone now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters your quick deletion probably [saved answerers rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601)

Comment: @gnat: then the community should just have deleted it ages ago. It's 258 points tops, anyway, hardly something the OP is going to notice against their 155k.

Comment: @MartijnPieters to avoid misunderstanding, I am neither happy nor unhappy about that. :) "community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..." ([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Comment: For a moment I thought this question was about an answer to a question with a historical lock turning up in review.

Comment: Thanks @animuson, will go forward with deletion going forward.