# Why is Stack Overflow so much concerned with taking away reputational profit from users?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I noticed a loss of 5 reputation points from my account due to a deleted user's account who had an upvote on one of my questions.

It got me thinking, reputation is lost when posts are deleted even after years. Bounty reputation is not refundable, and there are so many reasons for users to watch their hardly earned reputation points vanish into thin air.

Why is the reputation system that strict on users?

Comment: So, at least for bounties: they arent to REWARD (exclusively, at the very least). Think of them as a newspaper ad. You pay whether someone calls or not. You pay for visibility. That's why that one isn't refundable

Comment: "reputation is lost when posts are deleted even after years" - can you please provide link confirming it?

Comment: Just measure everything in a different unit, and it doesn't seem like quite as much. 5 rep from losing an upvote `:-(`, but 5.6 microSkeets `:-)`. 500 rep bounty `:-(`, but a half a milliSkeet bounty `:-)`. (Just be warned: like the speed of light, you can approach 1 Skeet, but you can never actually get there unless you're massless, and you can certainly never exceed 1 Skeet.)

Comment: lol. If anything the system is way too concerned with *not* taking away reputation. Hence silly rules like that deleted posts older than 60 days aren't subtracted rep-wise.

Comment: "reputational profit"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [R]eputation is lost when posts are deleted even after years.

No, [this is wrong.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/6083675) Unless you're talking about ~20 rep or a very new post, but otherwise you have this so blatantly wrong.

But really, why care so much about 20 rep (or *5* as you mentioned in your question `:P`)? Just answer something else and get some more. In your case, the post isn't deleted, so if it's good, it should get more upvotes.

[From the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> First, if you've contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. "Worthwhile" here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

Answer (score 2):

The reputation points need to be predictable so there are not any mistakes. Therefore you can't keep the points from the delete users, because they doesn't exist and on recalculation they won't match up. Otherwise people would create temporary users just to give them-self reputation and removing their accounts to wipe out the evidence.

If a bounty would be refundable, it wouldn't work, because half of the questions would have bounties on them and people could trick the system to get the points back after they got their answer. Basically the bounty is the price for the attention, similar as you're paying for the advert to promote on the first page - you don't get refunds because nobody replied.

See also:

- [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/191655)
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/191655)
- [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

Comment: The reputation page also links to the blog post in Laurel's answer: *Deleted posts do not affect reputation, for voters, authors or anyone else involved, in [most cases](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).*