# Delete voting shows an out-of-context warning

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete

I was handling some of the delete requests for the [Cleanup 500 old terse answers that either have hidden value or indicate awful questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334866/cleanup-500-old-terse-answers-that-either-have-hidden-value-or-indicate-awful-qu)  when I was met with a somewhat frightening pop-up:

[image]

that clearly states that I'm doing naughty things and that I'm going to be blocked from asking questions. Notice that I'm not deleting my own question ...

Now I'm sure some of the meta-crowd would love to see me being suspended or at least reprimanded for all the delete and close votes I cast but I think this popup wasn't meant to appear at this moment.

I believe this bug can be reproduced if you arrive on a question and between you casting the first delete vote an another member cast their vote first.

This scary pop-up doesn't reappear after you refresh the page. You do notice the delete link to have changed in *delete (1)*. For science I continued delete voting so if this is not a bug then suspensions are obviously handed out manually.

Nervously waiting for a response, I hope for [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ....

Comment: This bug only occurs if you have too many tabs open in your browser ;)

Comment: @honk Those are not many tabs. If you see the spikes of death: http://imgur.com/a/SAZxD then you have many tabs open.

Comment: "I'm sure some of the meta-crowd would love to see me being suspended..." I'm sure that's not true! I'm also sure the reptilians have come from deep within Mars to subliminally take over the world.

Comment: To confirm, are you saying that this popup is wrong because it's implying _you_ wrote the question you're deleting?

Comment: you could actually tell why you think this popup shouldn't have appeared, for us who didn't figure it out ourselves

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, that is the issue.

Comment: @eis I like to tease the brains but I can imagine on a Monday you're not into that. Added a small hint to the report.

Comment: @Rizier123 Maybe you would like [vertical tabs](http://i.imgur.com/7uzcBSi.png) :)

Comment: Is the close message banner supposed to be so pale or just an effect of blurring?

Comment: I see you finally clicked that +12384 rep

Comment: don't worry. stop thinking about it. it is just a warning: DO NOT DELETE. nothing more, nothing less.