# Why is my historic question about finding resources deleted?

Tags: discussion

One week ago, [my (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237824/are-there-tutorials-and-resources-explaining-all-components-of-guava-libraries) had 45 upvotes, no downvotes, 26 stars, 9k views and 6 helpful answers. It was in the top 15 questions of the Guava tag, and people regularly updated the various answers to keep them correct. In short, it was a helpful question with appropriate activity for over six years. Okay, granted, my 6 years-old wording wasn't the best, but no one ever corrected that, despite fixing some tags. When I Google for "guava documentation" (without the quotes), I get this link on the first page, right after the official Javadoc, the official Github page and the Wikipedia page. I don't think there's even 1% of 6 year old question that have these stats (if I'm wrong, just tell, don't come down on me like predators). I've asked more viewed, more upvoted questions, I don't think they come close to being as important as this one.

In one week, this question was closed, downvoted several times and then deleted today.

The most probable answer will be that "hey, now we have SO docs so your question is much *badder* than all we'll be able to put on SO docs". Well I'm still waiting for it to happen on Guava. Guava is a complex tool and I've already pondered for a serious amount of time how I'd put all the samples needed to it in a few documentation topics, limited to 13 examples each. Well, it's just not possible: Guava is just too complex for that. So SO docs is not appropriate for documenting Guava, bar from giving exact answers or links to documentation.

The second most probable answer is "linkz only, dood, iz bad". Well, yep, you got me. All answers are basically link-only answers. Yet, they have a decent amount of upvotes, meaning that they are helpful for various people. Again, despite being "link-only", it reached the first page of Google for "guava documentation" and <del>is</del> was helpful to many.

In six years, lots have changed on SO, asking for resources has become banned. I get it for new questions. But why target this old question at all? SO has more than 10 million questions. What made it so outstanding and so needed for deletion after all this time? While there are new "where can I find a tutorial for XXX?" everyday that aren't closed (despite my calls for close). From what I see from SO's actions, it's like one guy shooting himself in the foot: less visibility from question with higher traction.

No, I just don't get why this question is closed (and even less why it's deleted). I would really love some enlightenment.

Also, it's super bad that I wasn't notified my question got 1. closed and 2. deleted. I kind of just wondered where I got a non-multiple-of-5 rep difference today, since I didn't downvote anthing.

P.S. I don't care about the rep. I think I didn't lose any point (yet) bar the two downvotes. I'll probably lose 350+ rep, when UTC's day++, but that's OK, it's not like I need them. It's just that I think that historic questions shouldn't be treated like that if they were OK at the time of posting.

Comment: The reason it was closed as off-topic was already told to you when it was closed -- it's asking for an off-site resource, and this is explicitly off-topic for this site. It was deleted for the same reason that it was closed.

Comment: Likely it was flagged by the close vote review team.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As I said, it wasn't told me that the question is off-topic: it was kind of left there on a post-it in case someone sometimes check it. SO should really, really push notifications when closing/deleting happens. I'm glad someone while deleting also downvoted: I wouldn't have seen it before I wanted to edit one of the answers otherwise. Also, it *was* on topic until someone decided to change the rule a few years ago.

Comment: Your question was targeted by [a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=33081188#33081188).  Judge, jury and executioners gather there.  The site is under attack by low quality posts and it does not matter that this Q+A is 6 years ago and helpful to many dozens of users, collateral damage is not their concern.  They only put energy in the crap, not the questions that *need* to be answered.  It is a lot easier, anybody can do that, answering questions is hard work.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, this is probably more helpful than the other answers/comments so far.

Comment: @HansPassant judge was the community when they upvoted and approved [a clean up for answers that consists of mostly a link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334866/792066), yet you decided to be silent about it. Kind of late to shoutout *now* when you had plenty time to suggest a solution for the problem back then...

Comment: Hmya, I did see that post.  Looked pretty innocent when he asked for help to *improve* highly upvoted link-only answers.  That the executioners interpreted that as a signal to delete questions that were unlucky enough to get a good short answer is the usual collateral damage.  The solution is already entirely too obvious for me to state it explicitly: don't delete highly appreciated posts.  Duh.

Comment: "...and people regularly updated the various answers to keep them correct." No they didn't. Your own answer was the only answer updated in the last year. None of the others had been touched since 2011.

Comment: @BilltheLizard did they need update? When they did, they got it.

Comment: Yes, they all needed updating. They were link-only answers.

Answer (score 14):

Considering its age, you probably won't lose any reputation from its removal, so that's a non-concern.

Insofar as to why it was removed:  well...it's asking for tutorials.  That's now very much explicitly off-topic.  While you do acknowledge this, what seems to be missing is that this helps us alleviate the "broken windows" problem; we have a lot of old questions hanging around here which are explicitly off-topic, but people still see and believe that it's a good thing to have around.

Also, as you've likely surmised, there's a *bunch* of link-only answers; some of which are outdated, many of which are broken.  Even if this question *should* have been saved, the answers it had would've been its only redeeming value, and those offer much in the way of redemption.

Removing this question helps us clean up one broken window, regardless of its age.  There's little value in changing our policy and focus on what we want to allow here if we still have ancient examples which aren't really all that good to keep around.

As to how many people it impacted, there were only ~9,000 views on this topic from 2010, which is about ~1,500 views per year, so it wasn't one of these questions getting a lot of eyeballs on it.

Comment: We'll, another stat then: how many questions have a 1 upvote / 200 views after 5+ years? Not much. So it probably wasn't that visible, but it was that helpful.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire The problem is that the question is off topic. Yes, it may have been preserved for historical reasons, but the other main problem with the question are the many link only answers. In theory, these could be salvaged by providing updated links **along with any relevant content from the links added as text in the post** (e.g. don't rely on embedded images or links to pdfs and presentations). However, since the question is already off topic... it's unlikely it would be undeleted since it's already been deleted due to its off-topic status, even if the link-only issues were fixed.

Comment: In other words, you can fix the content problems in the answers but not the off-topic status, so remediating them is probably not worth the effort. This scenario is *exactly* why we consider link-only answers to be a bad thing.