# Include a JIT help for LOA which would be flagged as NAA

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, not-an-answer

Considering that it isn't immediately obvious that we can fix link only answers by extracting the relevant information from links, and [Shog's effort to make anyone aware of this option in meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339965/792066) I feel that his efforts are not enough. I propose a JIT message appended (lets call it flag tips?) to a answer flagged as not an answer that:

- Has score +10 and

  - More than the 80% of the content is within the <a> element or
  - It's less than 50 characters long without counting the <a> element
- ???
- Profit?

Obviously, the conditions are kind of simplistic. I was thinking of taking into account the score of other answers, to help on those cases where there's a answer that references the same document making the new answer redundant.

The message should promote the extraction of the relevant content of the off site, with a link to the editor, maybe with a boilerplate?

A proof of concept that manage the logic:

```
let flagform = document.querySelector("div#popup-flag-post")
let answerflag = document.getElementById("answer-" + flagform.dataset['postid'])
let votecount = answerflag.getElementsByClassName("vote-count-post")[0].textContent

if (actionselected.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value ===
    "AnswerNotAnAnswer" &&
   votecount > 10) {
    flagform.getElementsByClassName("popup-actions").append(flagtips)
}
```

It lacks a observer, to watch when the flag modal appears, and the message.

Comment: We need more TLAs in the title.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work for a relatively small number of answers. [gnat's cleanup effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334866/cleanup-500-old-terse-answers-that-either-have-hidden-value-or-indicate-awful-qu) almost certainly did more good than this would ever accomplish.

Comment: @Shog9 I think that just raising awareness is reason enough. BTW, the numbers can be tweaked.

Comment: What we really need is JIT help for all of these TLAs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This query isn't perfect](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/606048?MaxAnswerLength=512&MinScore=10&MaxBodyLengthWithoutUrl=50), but it suggests a ballpark figure of 1300 answers on Stack Overflow where you'd want this kicking in.

For scale, that's about two days worth of "not an answer" flags, 93% of which are marked Helpful. More people have read [that rant about apples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) than there are answers which would qualify by these metrics.

And... Truth is, almost no one flags answers that score >= 10, regardless of what other factors are involved; they have to look *really bad* to generate flags. In the entire history of Stack Overflow, there've only been a bit over 6700 answers scoring 10 or greater flagged as NAA. And just over 1400 of those have been declined... Which means we're still getting 80% accuracy even in these unfavorable conditions.

Meanwhile, there are hundreds of utterly inappropriate "answers" being flagged and deleted every day. And of those "Not an answer" flags declined, the most common reason is "no evidence", followed by "don't flag for technical inaccuracies". The most common *score* for answers with declined flags is 0, followed by -1, followed by 1.

In short, if we wanted to raise awareness of something here, it'd probably be "read the answer more carefully" followed by "wrong answers are still answers". If you think of ways to do *that*...

For all the complaints about these answers, flagging them disproportionately affects people who hang out on meta a lot and *probably already know* that they're taking a bit of a gamble; if not, I'm always happy to remind them of their ability to edit when a flag doesn't have their desired effect.

Comment: Cool, SEDE don't include the flags info. Which why skews my observations that you write at least every other week a post about this, and the ye olde complain about declined flags that we see every day. About the query, my intent with the score was to only foment fixing arguably worthy answers, if I try to go down towards 0, the eligible post seems to increase exponentially (score = 3 alone adds 1.6k).