# What to do with this high-voted Link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, link-only-answers

I've recently seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22362994/4927984). It has a lot of upvotes, but it is still a link-only answer.

Moreover this answer is slightly off-topic in view of the question (tell about server config on an AngularJS question).

Note that the question already have a [good and complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/4927984).

**What should we do with this specific answer?**

Comment: 76 voters found it useful can't it be edited into shape instead of deleting?

Comment: related: [Cleanup 500 old terse answers that either have hidden value or indicate awful questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334866/839601)

Comment: Now It has 75 upvotes the best anyone can do is to copy edit from the provided link.

Comment: Still a link only answer. It's only a matter of time until it becomes worthless.

Comment: Updating the link to the [wayback machine url](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20150513014458/https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) is trivial.

Comment: Link only answers are still considered "not an answer", or so I thought.

Comment: @yivi I agree, but flagging them is risky. As the answer is "popular", you may have flag declines.

Comment: And now it's gone.

Comment: It shouldn't had to be deleted at this stage IMHO!

Comment: I disagree @Abhishekgurjar, the question had much better and correct answers, and as it stood, the answer didn't provide value. And I don't like much the idea of making this kind of exceptions. We have good rules, and **no good reason** no to follow them.

Comment: @yivi It is debatable, the question has only three answer now with accepted answer, I've seen questions where even top 5 answers didn't worked for various reasons for some user, the upvotes on that questions declares that the solution in whatever form worked for some user, but still before deletion It can be edited with contents from link.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar, everything is debatable, sure. Then we should allow link only answers by default? Or for a time until we see if enough people upvote them? But people **will** upvote LO answers, because the answer may help _them_, but not the necessarily the site. Could the answer been edited? Yup. I guess the onus was on the answer's OP on editing it. Maybe he still can? I don't know, it never happened to me. But no matter what, the answer did go against SO policies.

Comment: @yivi yes, he can still edit, there is good guide [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) if one has to write link only answer because short descriptive answer are still allowed on SO.