# I asked an off-topic question, but now what?

Tags: support, questions

So I asked an off-topic question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403337/github-pages-documentation-and-jekyll-documentation. At first, I didn't realize it was off-topic, but now I realize that it absolutely is.

What is the best thing to do when your question has been flagged like this?

Comment: Learn from it (and from the [help files](https://stackoverflow.com/help)) so it does not happen again.

Comment: I definitely did learn from it, but I can still lose reputation for it, is there a way I can close it myself? Should I delete it?

Comment: It will no doubt be closed shortly by the community, but that does not prevent further down-votes (only deleting it will - but that is entirely up to you)

Comment: I see, so if I wanted to do damage control, deleting it and learning my lesson would be my best bet?

Comment: I would say so. You have asked enough positive questions so that deleting that one wont lead to any question ban.

Comment: If it was an answer, I would suggest the trick of turning into a community wiki (which don't change your rep either direction), but I don't think you can do that to questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question can be flagged off topic for a variety of reasons. If you believe it can be edited into shape to fit the norms outlined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then you should do so. If not, delete your question.

Relevant links that you should keep in mind are:

- [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

It's okay to make mistakes, as long as you learn from them. In the future, please try to keep your questions on topic, and to the point.

Comment: If the two alternatives are only "reshape" and "delete", then most of OLD closed questions should be deleted, as it's been years they didn't get reshaped. Yet, we're keeping many OLD closed questions for posterity, ranking, whatever.

Comment: Come on, @Cœur, have a little heart.

Comment: @Cœur Here ya go: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334866/cleanup-500-old-terse-answers-that-either-have-hidden-value-or-indicate-awful-qu