# Are we supposed to edit answers ourselves now, instead of flagging as NAA?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

I flagged revision 2 of https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10120467/revisions as NAA. It's a classic case for the flag.

A moderator declined my flag:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

And then proceeded to edit the answer, see revision 3.

I'm not aware of any policy changes. Are we supposed to edit the answers now instead of flagging them?

Comment: You are always encourage to improve the post if it is salvageable.  Why git rid of something we can fix?

Comment: In my opinion this should be a comment, so it's NAA.

Comment: I've flagged a few NAAs recently and had them accepted. They were more obviously NAA than the answer in question. That is arguably an answer; just an extremely poor, vague, link only one.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've flagged tons of answers like that one before, without problems. A moderator deletes the answer or converts it to a comment, or regular users review it and a comment is generated along the lines of "it is better to include the essential information ...", giving the poster a chance to fix their answer.

Comment: That looks like an attempt to answer the question, granted it is a poor attempt but it still does look like it could be an answer.

Comment: I thought that a NAA flag was not intended for moderator action, but for community review.

Comment: @yivi It is but after a while (I forget the exact amount) the flag goes into the mod queue.

Comment: @Stijn The more I look at it the more I think the mod should have marked the flag as helpful.  It needed to be improved so flagging was an appropriate choice.  Just because the mod decide he could improve it doesn't mean he should have declined the flag as he would never have seen it without that flag.

Comment: @NathanOliver it's an hour or two IIRC but because of positive score this "answer" would [go through mod review anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601)

Comment: It's a poor answer to a terrible question. It doesn't seem particularly wise to spend effort in polishing that at all.

Comment: It is not exactly a secret that SO is missing a deletion-is-good culture.  Wikipedia deletes about 2000 articles every day, we can't touch that kind of number.  This starts with the company putting up major obstacles and ends with the moderators not being very inclined to be the fall guys.  The last mod that was a deletionist did not survive long.   Only sane advise to offer is to just not leave it up to anybody else.  And to look at the question first to see if it is the source of the problem.  What the heck could anybody do with a "doesn't work" and the "code is over here" question.

Comment: Just me or hasn't this question been on the community bulleting for a long while?

Comment: The revision 2 is an answer, or start of an answer. Just from the content there, without the link, one could google their way to caniuse.com and answer their question. That is not what NAA flags are for, and the argument that "But I've flagged so many stuff like that with success in the past" is greatly invalid. People have burned women because they thought they were witches in the past, it is no reason to continue doing so.

Answer (score 11):

That post ***was*** an answer, even in its original state. It was on that basis that I declined your flag.

Although not of an especially high quality, the answer was of the "teach a man to fish" variety: it pointed them to a source that they could use to ascertain whether *any* new web technology is supported in a browser, which not only answered the original question, but also answered a much larger problem.

As an *independent* action, I decided that the answer could be *improved* slightly by editing it, so I did that. The edit and the flag decline were not connected, other than temporally (your flag brought the answer to my attention).

Honestly, that an answer omits a trivial, implied phrase like "the API is not supported" does not mean it is not an answer. It was quite obvious to 5 upvoters what the answer meant, and it was quite obvious to me. I'm not even a web developer. So yeah—in cases where adding a trivial, implied phrase to an answer is necessary to convert it into an answer in your eyes, you should edit instead of flagging.

I also tend to share Brad Larson's [extremely unpopular opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332611) regarding extremely old, upvoted answers. Obviously a number of people have found them useful, so it's arguably harmful to the site for a moderator to simply delete them. When the links are dead, and that's all there was to the answer, I will generally delete it. But if the answer still retains all of its original value, then I'm probably going to choose to keep it around.

But before y'all fire up the flamethrowers, I'll point out that I processed some 300+ flags yesterday and marked the overwhelming majority of NAA/VLQ flags as "helpful", deleting the flagged answers in the process. It's not like I'm choosing to keep around most of what gets flagged. This was, however, a pretty clear case where deletion appeared to me to be counter-indicated. If it possible to add value, rather than destroy it, then I strongly prefer the former.

Another fun fact: the Low Quality Posts review queue was holding at a *very* manageable quantity all day yesterday, and there were several occasions where posts that I clicked through to from the moderator flag dashboard had already been deleted by community members through review. This is good. That answer was in the queue for about an hour and didn't get *any* reviews. So, plenty of active reviewers, only a small number of posts to be reviewed—the logical conclusion is that reviewers were skipping it because they were unsure. Another good argument not to delete it.

Comment: discussed answer (flagged revision) would turn into useless sequence of ASCII symbols if caniuse.com gets unavailable: _"when you try using new web-technology please check caniuse.com for browser support - in this case http://caniuse.com/fileapi tells you everything you need to know ;)"_

Comment: Nobody ever considers the Way Back Machine as a suitable backup, odd.  That URL is captured well with 74 copies.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say that it'd turn into a "useless sequence of ASCII symbols", but I really dislike "browser support" answers like this that go out of their way to hide the actual answer while simultaneously trying to make it seem like it should be obvious to the reader. When someone is trying that hard, I don't consider it a good-faith attempt to answer. The only defense this answer has, really, is that it's the *only* one, and that it's unlikely the flagger would be bothered to post their own answer as a replacement even if they really wanted to see this one gone.

Comment: yeah... first thing I do when bumping into dead link while searching for solutions to my programming problems is check it at Wayback Machine. Because at this moment I am most interested to find what could be hidden behind that cryptic 404 at the page that was removed many years ago... not! what I really do is drop the useless answer and go to next search result

Comment: Note: This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106981/html-5-file-api-doesnt-work-on-ie/10120467#comment12948677_10106981) was posted roughly 20 hours before that answer, and does a much better job of explaining the problem - in lesser words.

Comment: Yes, I agree, @Nisarg. Had that comment been posted as an answer, it would have been an easier decision to delete the flagged answer. It wasn't, though, so I'm not sure how that's relevant.

Comment: The original answer *probably* was link-only maybe a dispute and then edit would have been a nice action that also avoids meta discussions and let you spend your time improving SO which you seem to be doing with excellency.

Comment: @Petter Moderators cannot dispute these types of flags. The only flags we can dispute are "spam" and "rude or abusive". For everything else, "helpful" and "declined" are all you get.