# Why is this answer still around?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

I ran across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50749057/2370483) last week.

> You won't need this soon since public API will be available next week. Documentation is almost ready.
>
> Write to [some email here] if you want to get early access to docs.

Amazingly, it dodged a bullet in the LQP with a [3-3 review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19960892). In the meantime, someone (not the OP) [edited in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20012641) which really didn't improve anything. I reflagged it NAA which got [inexplicably edited out of queue](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50749057/3) (I'm not sure what that edit improved, if anything).

So I raised a mod flag with this comment

> This is a poor answer since it simply says there will be an API soon (and then adds only a link). At best it's a comment. First set of reviewers OKed it and someone edited it out the second time. Needs removal as an answer

which was declined.

Is this really a post worth having around?

Comment: You have > 20K. Why don't you delete it your self? Or at least started it? Heck, you even have a whole chatroom at your disposal ...

Comment: @rene Was at +1 at the time. Some flower doesn't like voting rings and stuff...

Comment: @rene ^ this is why I believe there is a missing pathway of signaling.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yeah, the review history on that was kind of a mess, invalidating two separate "not an answer" flags via questionable edits and reviews. The voting there is also a little weird.

I can't speak for the moderator who declined your custom flag, but I don't think that answer stands on its own or adds anything to the existing detailed answer. I've deleted it as a result.

Comment: I've always found weird that editing a post in the LQP completes the review. People normally don't know it and, as a result, things that are about to get deleted finally stay around.

Comment: Did you think that maybe this answer was kept because it contains useful information? When deleting, did you bother to move this information into a comment? Are you here to enforce rules, or to help people?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky - Trust me, I'm usually the one [arguing to keep answers around](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332611/19679) despite strong Meta sentiment to remove them. In this case, I didn't see how that answer added anything on top of the existing detailed answer there, or even how it addressed the specific question asked. Even as a comment, I didn't think it had additional value. I can be convinced otherwise, though, and move it to a comment somewhere else there.