# How to vote on an answer to edited question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, specific-question, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895116/749227) currently doesn't address the question in its current state at all. I was going to downvote the answer and explain why with a comment. Then I read both the answer and the question more closely and realized that the question had been edited (probably appropriately so since it focused it and removed a bit that was aimed at opinion rather than what is usually considered quality SO question material) and that the answer did address the part that was removed.

See [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22213098/revisions).

Even if the original version of the question asked something less appropriate for SO, should the answerer be downvoted for a good answer that no longer applies?  I'm hesitant to downvote the answer when it was really the question that needed work.

Comment: There were two questions in the original, and the answer focused on the one that was removed.  It now looks like the answer isn't addressing the question at all. Q1 = "how do I...", Q2 = "why do people prefer...".  Removing Q2 doesn't change Q1, but it materially changes what the OP asks, no?

Comment: OK, looks you're right. Rolling back the edit would be the right action then. Editing questions in a way that invalidates existing answers isn't an appropriate action.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, the edit to the question is what makes the question acceptable.  That there's an answer doesn't change that.  That someone posts a bad answer to a bad question doesn't mean that nobody should then be allowed to make that quesiton actually be appropriate for fear of invalidating the bad answer.  It's changing a question to ask something completely different than it was originally asking that's a problem, and that's orthogonal to whether or not there's an answer.

Comment: @Servy Hmm, moving targets are a tricky field anyways :P

Comment: It does seem like a catch-22.  Either the question is prevented from being improved or we put the burden on answerers to only risk answering if they feel the question is good (and that it won't materially change in the future).  I personally think I'm leaning towards improving questions and letting the chips fall where they may as far as answers go.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which is why you shouldn't be answering questions that aren't appropriate for the site.   You should be waiting to have a good question, at which point you know the fundamental question being asked won't change.  It's also why we don't want to have multiple questions in a question.

Comment: Keep in mind that we specifically don't want questions like the question edited out here specifically because we don't like answers like this answerer posted.  `should the answerer be downvoted for a good answer that no longer applies?` I'd reject the premise that this is a good answer.

Comment: K, a downvote on the answer seems in order then

Comment: @jinglesthula Yes.

Comment: Nah.  Just close the browser tab and let's all pretend this didn't happen.

Comment: @Will I think questions that are edited and thereby "orphan" answers probably happens from time to time.  Having the discussion will hopefully help others who may run across a similar situation who also wonder how to approach it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The edit on the question was right and it shouldn't be rolled back. Firstly, questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to contain only one actual question, because otherwise they'd be too broad (unless the questions are very closely related, but that's not the case here). Secondly, the second question ("Why does everyone like spaces more than tabs?") was definitely primarily opinion-based, which means it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

As for the answer: people shouldn't answer questions which doesn't meet SO standards in the first place. The answer answers only the second question, which doesn't meet SO standards, so it's perfectly fine to downvote this answer. I would even consider flagging it for moderator attention to delete it, as it doesn't address the question in its current state.

Answer (score 9):

OP of the answer in question here. When I posted that answer, there was an answer which correctly answered only half of the original question. I posted an answer, based on my own experience, which answered the second half. I am still pretty new to stack exchange in general, and it's hard for me to tell what makes a good or bad question.

I'm not sure what effect down votes have other than on the order of the answers, but if you want to down vote my answer, feel free.

In the future, do I wait to answer questions to see if they're appropriate, or just use my best judgement?

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be generally not answered. Making an answer to the question doesn't make it right.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not an answer to the meta question.  It's a great comment, or even a new (linked/related) question.  But it is not an answer.

Comment: I sincerely don't mean to make SO feel unfriendly to newer members.  Voting is intended to be a way to collectively identify what best answers the question and isn't meant personally (either pos. or neg.).  This and the first couple links on the right are good info on what makes for a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As a side note, the other effect aside from the order of questions is a small rep loss.  I think this is designed to encourage good answers.  "Punish" was the wrong word for me to use (and I appologize sincerely - that was careless of me; I've edited the question to focus on the content).  I think SO is heavily built on a system of incentives that aims to produce very useful Q&A.  The only real punishment is for abuse of the system and is more like blocking/banning.  The rest is just attempting to shape the content of the site a certain way.

Comment: @jinglesthula as far as I can tell in this case deleting the answer won't result in rep loss, at least until [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773) downvotes drop its score under +3. See [Can we please clear misunderstanding that deleting old highly upvoted posts causes reputation loss?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601)

Comment: re: last para: use your best judgement about what to answer.  It's not a disaster if other people disagree with you when you legitimately thought a question deserved an answer and had future value for future readers.  Just keep in mind that it *is* better not to answer some questions.  For questions with future value, I may try to help the OP in a comment after downvoting, if I'm feeling generous with my time, and there's something useful I can point out or link them to. Otherwise I just downvote bad questions, or sometimes leave them alone if they're yet another newbie debugging question.