# Why not close as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons

In review of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445794/125981 the accepted answer ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/679tS.png)) is just a link to another question.  I was at first simply tempted to close as a duplicate. Any reason why I should NOT do so?
Is it appropriate to down vote the answer as it apparently SHOULD have been a "close as duplicate" vote in the first place?

Comment: Well the answer is very old, the user who answered probably didn't know about how to flag or the flag for duplicate might not exist back then. I will say go for it.

Comment: I've converted that link-only answer to a comment now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do users loose rep when their answers are converted to comments?

Comment: @mega6382: the answer is deleted; it depends on the age and the score of the post if deletion costs them rep. In this case, only the +15 is lost, the rep for up and downvotes is retained, because the answer is over 60 days old and has a score of 3 or higher.

Comment: @mega6382 see [Can we please clear misunderstanding that deleting old highly upvoted posts causes reputation loss?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601)

Comment: Suppose the answer is very old and things have changed in the language or technology. Sometimes I see a lot of questions getting marked as duplicate and linking to a very old question as old as 10 years. As a beginner you have to wonder whether the answer is reliable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I was at first simply tempted to close as a duplicate. Any reason why I should NOT do so?

You shouldn't vote to close the question as a duplicate just because someone else posted an answer saying that the other question answers the question.  You should look at the other question yourself, and if you feel that it answers the question, feel free to flag it as a duplicate.  This isn't a situation where you can just take someone's word for it that it's a duplicate.

> Is it appropriate to down vote the answer as it apparently SHOULD have been a "close as duplicate" vote in the first place?

An answer that just links to another question *isn't even an answer*.  Flag the post as Not An Answer.  A downvote is also fine.

Comment: Indeed, the comment on the non-answer has a point. I quote: *"I don't think the OP's intention was to clone a new object, looks more like updating the values of properties of an already existing object to another one"*. As written it doesn't look like it actually is a duplicate of the linked question. But the OP accepted the answer nonetheless... What a mess.

Comment: @Gimby This is why unclear and poorly specified questions are a problem.

Comment: I agree with both you and @Gimby, The key here is the "duplicate" is the accepted answer to the question, now OTHER answers do IMHO add value but does the OP here really have the "final vote" on it really being a duplicate by that acceptance vote?  Note I am not in the habit of down voting in general.  But, I do often attempt to "clean up" poorly formed questions.

Comment: Well, the OP did accept that answer, so that's a strong indicator that it was helpful in solving the problem. Also, the answer has been converted to a comment now.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Downvoting low quality content when you see it is very important.  You should make it a habit of downvoting bad content that you see, rather than leaving without the proper feedback.

Comment: @Servy I think MarkSchultheiss's coming to meta was also a good idea, as it got the community involved to find out how to deal with it.

Comment: If I DO down vote, I nearly always put some comment as to why in hope that the poster will consider improvements, and often even when I do not down vote - better is better and sometimes when comments go unheeded I will subsequently down vote, sort of a "lead them to water but if they don't react, hand them a drink before tossing them in".

Comment: _"This isn't a situation where you can just take someone's word for it that it's a duplicate"_ -- not that it matters anymore, but I think this is in fact such a situation, because the "someone" in this case is the original author of the question. I agree you certainly shouldn't take just anyone's word for it, but if the person who wrote the question agrees that the link to some other Q&A does in fact provide the best answer to their question, that seems like a pretty good and reliable indication it's a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho People accept answers that don't actually answer the question.  The OP isn't infallible.  If you've read the OP's question, and the answers to the linked question, and honestly feel yourself that the other question answers it, then that's great, close it as a duplicate, but if you don't think that it answers the question, don't close it as a duplicate just because someone else thinks that it's a duplicate.