# Why would a VLQ answer not be deleted even though the reviewers voted to delete it?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

[This link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7399159/4032703) recently [went through the VLQ queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17957440). All four reviewers voted "Recommend Deletion," but the post is still there, and the edit history says nothing about it having been deleted or undeleted.

Image:
[image]

That being the case, why wasn't it deleted? The fact that all four reviewers voted for it to be deleted doesn't appear to have made any difference whatsoever.

Comment: ...also worth referring: [Can we please clear misunderstanding that deleting old highly upvoted posts causes reputation loss?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601) (though definitely not a duplicate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the post has a positive score, it can't be deleted by reccomend deletion votes in the review queue.  Those votes have simply resulted in an auto-flag for a moderator stating that the review queue thinks a well received post merits deletion, and the mod can then determine if deletion is in fact merited.  The flag has most likely has not yet been reviewed yet, given how recent the review is.

Comment: Interesting... can it be deleted by higher-rep users?

Comment: @EJoshuaS You cannot cast a delete vote on an answer without a negative score.  It would need to attract 12 downvotes before any delete votes could be cast.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I figured there was some kind of a logical explanation.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Note that my previous comment applies to answers.  The question is eligible for delete votes by 10k users (which of course takes the answer along with it).  Note that I don't think this question merits deletion (I don't think it does), just saying it's technically possible for someone to cast the vote.