# How to deal with an old, sub-par question that gained a lot of popularity

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, moderation, old-questions

I have recently bumped into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json) question.

I think this should be closed and deleted, as it isn't (and arguably has never been) appropriate for Stack Overflow: it basically just asks "how to parse this JSON with Java and do something with it".

Literally, quoting OP:

> [...] What is the required code?

If a similar question was posted today, it would be downvoted into oblivion very quickly - however this one seems to have slipped through the cracks and gained a lot of popularity - in fact, it is getting linked as duplicate when someone new asks for a "how to parse JSON with Java" generic question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547063/java-parse-an-string-url-request-from-a-database#comment84090663_48547063) for instance).

I have downvoted the question and voted to close (and mistakenly unprotected it, then protected it again once I realized my mistake).

I also asked for moderator intervention, but was declined, arguably because mods are not there to close inappropriate, non-SPAM / non-offensive questions (at least that's the only reason I can come up with).

**TL;DR**

- **Edit II** (as this is controversial): The **question** itself (not talking about the page, i.e. the combination of bad question and good answers) should be closed and deleted under normal circumstances - I think this is a no brainer
- However, it has gathered a lot of popularity in the form of upvotes, and some pretty good answers too
- What to do?

Comment: The question has been closed now.

Comment: Since it's closed there's nothing else to do really

Comment: Questions can be locked, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion

Comment: @Chris_Rands questions closed **should be** improved. Locking doesn't solve any problem, just postpone it to infinity.

Comment: Maybe an historical lock. It has over 1M views

Comment: I also think the question should be gone, as in, deleted. That's what is going to be hard to manage I believe.

Comment: I agree with the historical locking. A question with that many views can have links pointing to it, people can use it as a reference, etc. The question might be sub-par, but the answers have probably helped lots of people (looking at the amount of upvotes). Deleting it just because we don't accept such questions nowadays would be a waste imo.

Comment: I understand historical locking may be a better compromise than just smashing it down. It still feels wrong to have such a high rep blatantly bad question around though - sets the wrong example in my opinion.

Comment: @Mena with regards to rep loss, please note that deleting won't work in this case. See [Can we please clear misunderstanding that deleting old highly upvoted posts causes reputation loss?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601)

Comment: @gnat didn't mean to forcibly cause rep loss to the OP. Don't really care. I just mentioned the rep because it's part of what makes the question "popular". So in my view, the fact that such a bad question is still visible and has a high rep is wrong in a way, because it sets a bad example all around.

Comment: [broken windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info), I see

Comment: @gnat indeed :)

Comment: do note the 467 questions that have been closed as duplicate to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2591098?lq=1

Comment: @SurajRao that's a good point, but it also reflects the "easy" solution for privileged users in my opinion: it's easier to close as duplicate than to close/delete when the question is unsalvageable, or assist the OP in improving their question if it can have a value. I believe the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547063/java-parse-an-string-url-request-from-a-database#comment84122488_48547063) that led me to this big one is actually in the grey area, and that's ultimately what prompted me to act upon.

Comment: @SurajRao on top of that, centralizing a dupe this way drives hordes of noobs onto the big, bad question (luckily it's protected, so no storms of low-level / bad answers), which will increase its visibility and potentially expose it to further upvotes. Which is quite the opposite of what's desirable, since it's a bad question.

Comment: Calling it blatantly bad is a bit of an overstatement, it's a poorly researched question at best (even back then). I'm sure plenty of people were introduced to their favorite JSON parser through this question, historical lock gets my vote too.

Comment: @Gimby it **is** blatantly bad. It just asks "gimme teh codez to parse this json". It's harder to see it now that it has so many upvotes and decent answers, which is exactly my point!

Comment: There's clearly a disconnect between your theoretical ideal of a good question and those that the community have found valuable in practice for whatever reason.

Comment: @MartinSmith just read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). That is not *my* theoretical idea of a good question, that's the rules. Arguably, rules weren't as strict back then.

Comment: Please be clear/summarize why it's sub-par: Lack of Effort (*"gimme teh codez"*), offtopic (library recommendation), too broad...? It's quite likely that various people think it's sub-par for different reasons. As @Makoto says, it was open and cited long enough that it became semi-canonical, how do you factor that in?

Comment: There are many, many questions like this across almost every tag. Many of them come from people who joined early on who were trying to get as much reputation as possible, quickly. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-to-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby?rq=1) question clearly shows no research effort, and would quickly be closed today with comments like "read the docs".

Comment: So the question is a bit too broad but some of the answers are really useful. It's the top hit when you Google ["how to parse json in java"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&ei=S0N0Wta0I4mpjwTEyqnICQ&q=how+to+parse+json+in+java&oq=how+to+parse+json+in+java) and it does answer the question. Asking for its deletion now is extremely petty in my opinion. We should really all have better things to do than go through old questions deleting them for no good reason.

Comment: " it is blatantly bad" 688 upvoters disagree with you.

Comment: @JeremyP not asking for deletion, asking what to do, which includes deletion as an option. If you think the question is so good, try asking one with the exact same format ("give me the code to parse this JSON in java") and feast your eyes upon the live-feed of downvotes. I'm kidding, just don't.

Comment: You are asking, or at least canvassing, for deletion. Your question specifically says that "the question should be closed, Edit: and deleted - I think this is a no brainer"

Comment: @MartinSmith reading myself back again, you're right - I *seem* too opinionated about it. My real point is that while the *question* is smite material, I do understand the context and am asking what the best solution is here, which has gathered some consensus so far on historical lock.

Comment: @JeremyP consider giving a read to [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: I don't care why the user asked it, or what kind of quality the actual question is. What I find frustrating is that the top answer has a bunch of comments saying how bad that library is, none of the answers have more votes than the question, and you have to sit there and go through more than 20 answers (I stopped counting) to find a solution that looks doable. It's just confusing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Sigh*...

Looking at the question in context...

- it was asked **in 2010**, back when SO was still trying to figure much of this out
- it has had a checkered past; [having been been put through close reviews and miraculously surviving until now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2591098/timeline)
- it has the **authoritative** answer to parsing JSON in Java (use a library, such as Gson, org.json, or Jackson)
- it has been seen over a million times
- it has [quite a lot of links *to* it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2591098?lq=1) (and would disrupt any questions which did link to it, either as a reference point or as a duplicate closure piece)

...and I get that its quality isn't up to our standards today, but I don't feel like *closing* it is the right choice.

"Closure" sends the message, "This question is not suitable for our site in its current state, but with some editing it *might* be in the future."  No amount of editing is going to make this question any more on-topic.

The issue with a historical lock is that answers then can't be updated, either.  Supposing a link to the documentation for any of those libraries changes, we're stuck with an old version that lots and lots of people *will* see and *will* attempt to access.

Perhaps something similar to how [the venerable NPE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) has been handled could be done; a *simple* lock on the question would fix the major issue of not being able to maintain anything.  Then, we could make a choice to either make the question community wiki and delete all other answers (since there only now needs to be one).

But closure?  C'mon.  This question's just a bit *too* valuable to be treated like the same garbage we normally get.

Comment: If it's so valuable, why not ask the right question? ie. How to parse JSON with <x list of constrains>? BTW, "having been closed and reopened before" nope, it has not, it has [been closed exactly *one time*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2591098/revisions), this time.

Comment: @Braiam:  Because the right question at the time really *was*, "how do I do this".  Not every question is going to magically fit into our constraints here.  The more  we resist that fact the harder it becomes to both address the reasons *why* they don't and to help the questions that aren't *quite* what we want but are still plenty serviceable.

Comment: Agreed with everything except for semantics: the *question* per se is not "too valuable", the (good) answers are.

Comment: @Braiam At the time it was asked, JSON was still the new hotness. SOAP was just going out of style. How you parse JSON wasn't an unreasonable thing to ask.

Comment: @Mena: I take "question" to mean "Q&A" here; after all, answers can't exist without a question to answer.

Comment: @BoltClock actually they can, just on another question ;)

Comment: @Braiam: I get that English isn't your first language, so allow me to explain: your statement *confirms* what I said about answers requiring a question to be attached to, whether it's this one, or another one. So, no, they *can't* exist on their own.

Comment: @BoltClock actually, I did understand your comment clearly, I'm making a nab to actually *asking another question where those answers can remain* ie. delete the current one and migrate over the content. Thank you.

Comment: My biggest beef with the post was the line *What is the required code?*, since removed by Mark Amery (thanks!). It was a blatant request for 'do my work for me'.

Answer (score 18):

This question should stay open, no historical lock and no deletion.

This is on-topic (possibly slightly too broad), low quality, high usefulness question.

Options:

- downvote due to low quality. Note that it is hard to claim that person did not research the topic well 8 years after post was made. Do you know what search results would show up in 2010 for "Java parse JSON" and how useful they were?
- edit post to be higher quality so it meets your / SO quality standards
- close as "too broad" or "search for tutorial" because you feel so.

I recommend editing question to meet your standards. Note that editing in research at that point is somewhat pointless and there is not code required as this is not a debugging question.

I'm also against historical lock as it will block possible updates to the question while the topic unlikely stop being poplar any time soon.

---

Note that I base my opinion influenced by similar post in tag I know more (C# - [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)) and I have only cursory knowledge of Java - so there could be good reasons why Java one awful and off-topic (which I'm not aware of).

Comment: I really think the programming language doesn't matter here. The root of my question can be summarized as: this is a question asking for code, not a question asking for a solution. It provides no effort whatsoever, it's just a request for code. Among the people who answered, some were well-intentioned enough to provide broad information on the available frameworks and in some cases, examples. Since then it has grown into the central hub for all noob Java/JSON questions and got a lot of upvotes. Many of the answers are good and the page is good, but the question is still garbage.

Comment: @Mena *"a question asking for code, not a question asking for a solution"* - what practical difference does that make? I don't see any; it seems like it's a matter of wording that doesn't affect the meaning of the question in any way.

Comment: @Mena Questions asking "How can I do X in language Y" [are not off topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x). The [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) seems to only describe two cases where code is required: "Why isn't this code working" questions and homework questions.

Comment: *possibly slightly too broad*: it asked for answerers to 'do my work for me' with the phrase *what is the required code?*, which is classic *too broad* territory. I'm glad to see that that has been removed now.

Answer (score 1):

> This question does not show any research effort [...]

– *Downvote button tooltip*

Downvoting is the most appropriate action for questions like this one.

Comment: vote split on discussed question currently shows +689/-20 I honestly can't see how downvotes are supposed to work

Comment: ...this is a long known thing about popular questions, "...it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..." ([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Comment: @gnat I feel you. I personally think it should be closed, but evidently that's not the consensus opinion. In fact, the question is on the way to being reopened! Downvoting, on the other hand, should be a no-brainer consensus on meta (given its definition). But yeah, I agree it isn't very effective. Still appropriate, in my opinion, though.