# Is "look into x" an acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Recently I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177239/2333214) as Not an Answer, but it was declined mentioning that

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

The answer contains the following:

> Look into `min-height`

I didn't flag it based on any technical inaccuracy, I simply don't see anything more than a comment that says, "Hey, go read up on x" (*And it doesn't even link to a good documentation for `x`*).

I haven't been active in meta for a while. If I remember correctly, answers that simply act as direction boards weren't considered answers...

Is this an acceptable answer..?

Comment: You've hit *the small patch between NAA and VLQ*. imo, downvote such stuff and leave a comment

Comment: @BhargavRao I though `VLQ` was supposed to be used when the content   is poorly worded/formatted and is beyond saving by editing..?

Comment: *between* VLQ and NAA. Such answers are better downvoted (imo again)

Comment: I've had the same experience with NAA and started flagging that kind of answer as VLQ (because the content of that answer **is** of a low quality) and I don't think I've seen any of those flags get rejected.

Comment: @ivarni yes, I retract my statement based on Cerbrus' answer and comment train

Comment: This is almost as bad as "Just Google it", which I see quite frequently on this site. It's bad because it alienates the user asking a question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's *not* an answer to the question posed.

It does not even attempt to be an answer to the question posed.

It attempts to be a signpost to some resource elsewhere that the OP could read to get their answer.

It's a comment (and, as a "hint"/"tip", one that should not have been posted even as such).

Flagging as NAA was correct. Sad to see the flag get declined.

Comment: It is an attempt to answer *a* question. This answer warrants downvotes, it warrant delete votes, but it does not warrant a flag. There is a reason users don't get delete votes until 20k.

Comment: The votes on the questions and answers here show us that the culture of meta wants to promote incorrect flagging, even at the expense of flaggers caught up in the mess who could be getting a lowered flag weight or possible flag bans due to the incorrect advice being given here.

Comment: [Shog's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) contains explicit examples that are almost exactly like this one, and he calls them an answer. [Tiny Giant's post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312145/1394393) links to it, by the way (although it doesn't explicitly mention how similar the examples are). Pretty sure he trumps mods.

Comment: For the record, I also don't see a single citation in your answer, while Tiny's post is chock full of authoritative information to the contrary.

Comment: I totally agree with this, and it's about time that SO changed what constitutes as low quality or NAA related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318919/how-long-should-a-mod-wait-before-reviewing-flags-for-the-low-quality-queue-to-g (look at the declined flags)

Answer (score 14):

This answer warrants **downvotes**, and possibly **delete votes** from users with greater than 20k reputation, but it ***does not*** warrant a flag.

That *is* an attempt to answer *a* question, as defined by:

- [A minor change to the description of the "not an answer" flag: "the question" → "a question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag)
- [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)

It does not have ***severe*** content or formatting problems, as defined by:

- [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag)
- [What qualifies as Very Low Quality, if not this?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260812/what-qualifies-as-very-low-quality-if-not-this)
- [What kind of answer should be flagged as "Very Low Quality", but not flagged as "Not an Answer"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111108/what-kind-of-answer-should-be-flagged-as-very-low-quality-but-not-flagged-as)
- [Questions on when to flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164770/questions-on-when-to-flag)
- [What does the "very low quality" flag mean in regard to answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122443/what-does-the-very-low-quality-flag-mean-in-regards-to-answers)

If you flagged the answer referenced in your question as Not an Answer or Very Low quality, then you flagged it wrong. This is a bad answer, it may even be a wrong answer, but it is *an* answer.

**The flagging system is not a substitute for delete votes.**

The reason that users need 20k rep before they get to cast delete votes is because otherwise we would end up with a lot of good content being deleted. I'm not saying that the content referenced in your question is good content, but it is not *flag-worthy* content.

**Relevant**:

- [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)
- [Should we handle flags more carefully..?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312330/should-we-handle-flags-more-carefully/312339#312339)

Comment: None of your VLQ links really mention extremely short answers like these. Just downvoting / delete voting those answers is, in my experience, ineffective. Usually, not enough 20k+ users see it / care enough to get to 3 delete votes. Flagging them as VLQ both gives the answer some extra attention (So, _if_ it is somehow salvageable, more likely someone that can comes across it), and helps getting rid of the answer. I've only ever has _4_ VLQ flags declined. Quite a few more were disputed, but that only means the answer _was improved_.

Comment: So you're argument is that the system *the way it is designed* is not good enough for you, so you would like to *misuse* a flag in order to bypass the system by *hoping* that the LQPRQ reviews handle the flag incorrectly?

Comment: My answer is based on what _works_ and what does _not work_. It has nothing to do with my opinion of the way the system was designed. None of the links you provided explain that "VLQ" should _not_ be used for answers that can _only_ be salvaged by completely rewriting them.

Comment: That answer is an answer all on its own, it does not require editing to make it an answer. It is completely understandable as it is.  It does not need salvaging, it could use improvement, but so could most every post on this site.

Comment: It's not an answer on it's own. It's like answering _"Use a pen"_ when someone asks how to start with calligraphy.

Comment: It is an incomplete answer for sure, but those *are* allowed as defined in the help center: "*Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.*"

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the general question, "Is 'Look into X' an acceptable answer", then in many cases it is, though perhaps not in the case of this specific question. It is an acceptable answer, in my view, if for example

(a) there is insufficient information in the question to allow a definitive answer, but enough information to suggest that X is an area worth investigating

(b) the question is looking for a programming construct to tackle a particular problem, and X is the construct that will solve the problem. For example Q: how do I eliminate duplicates from a set of numbers? A: look into using distinct-values().

Personally I'm a great believer in the idea that when someone asks how to get from A to B, pointing them in the right direction is more helpful than holding their hand and taking them there. We should not only be answering people's questions, we should be trying to help them tackle the next question on their own.

Comment: I'm no fan of spoon feeding either, but then most of the answers in stackoverflow will be link only, either a link to drive people to some blog post or RTFM... Of one does not care to take some time to  write an *answer* and merely wants to point someone somewhere, isn't it better for them to use the comments..?

Comment: "we should be trying to help them tackle the next question on their own." Nice sentiment, but SO is a Q&A site. The best answers do three things: 1) Answer the question (not just hint, otherwise this is not a Q&A site), 2) Explain the answer (e.g., clarify, discuss anything that a reasonable person might be confused about), and 3) In the process, explain something about how you would find such an answer to such a question in the future, what resources you use when you face such questions. 1-3 are in order of importance at a Q and A site, even if 3 might be more helpful to a new programmer.

Comment: So, if someone asks, how would I get from Oxford to Reading, is it an "answer" to say "Consider catching the X39 bus"? We don't know whether this is the best answer for them (we don't know how much time or money they have available and we don't know the exact start and end points of the journey). But it is one possible solution; it might be the best answer; it is one they should consider. It's incomplete, of course: we're leaving them to find out where the X39 goes from, how frequent it is, and how much it costs. But we're entitled to assume that they're capable of finding that information.

Answer (score 2):

*"Look into X"* *is* an answer: It is an attempt at answering the OP's question.
It's just very minor, and should probably be flagged as VLQ:

> **very low quality**
>   This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

As you can see, "VLQ" also applies to answers with severe *content* problems.
In my opinion, if an answer is *that* minor that it really doesn't contribute anything to the question, then that answer has a severe content problem.

Another option would be to downvote the answer.

Comment: Odd to see you recommend VLQ, as meta has discussed numerous times that it is mainly for gibberish. Its not gibberish, its actually legible enough to want to nuke it for what it represents. Ex: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag . Did the general consensus change?

Comment: @Gimbyin my observations, it depends on who handles the flag.  If you use VLQ, it does go to the community via the Low Quality Review Queue.  If the community handles it first, they may delete it for being a Low Quality answer.  If a moderator gets to it first, then you have a better chance of it being declined since it isn't gibberish.

Comment: _"Look into X"_ isn't gibberish, sure. As such, the contents of the answer are of decent quality. _However_, it doesn't add value to the question, and is better off being deleted. "VLQ" is a relatively reliable flag to get the answer reviewed. If the community disagrees, the post will stay.

Comment: @Gimby: Also, that post you linked is about VLQ flags on questions. Not about answers. Also, VLQ is not just for gibberish. (Edited my answer)

Comment: @Cerbrus aw man, that is not the first time I mix and mash metas for questions and answers.

Comment: But is it really "un-salvageable" through editing? I'm always afraid of using such flag since most of the things posted here can be improved through an edit.

Comment: The only way to salvage that answer would be to add info the answerer didn't provide... This is not something someone else should do.

Comment: @Cerbrus: _"This is not something someone else should do"_ -- true, but the guidance simply refers to "editing", not "editing by someone other than the author of the post". That said, in theory any bad post can be improved by editing, simply by replacing the entire contents with a good post, so I _do_ agree that the type of "editing" involved can be inferred to mean that the post is fundamentally sound and just needs cleaning up, as opposed to has nothing useful to offer. If a post is the latter type, that sure sounds like VLQ-fodder to me.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I agree. In my opinion, these answers fall in the latter category.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer is wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312127/16587) (I guess that's proof that an answer doesn't have to be correct to be marked 'accepted').

It's a terrible answer, but it is an answer. `min-height` will solve the OP's problem.

Of course, there are a lot of terrible answers on that question; but that's a symptom of the question, not of the answers.

In the future, if you really want to have answers deleted that are actual answers, be conservative in how you choose to flag it; if you believe that a moderator could reasonably construe an answer as an answer, don't flag it as "Not an answer", because your flag will be declined.

We sometimes use flags as audits; and so we're pretty particular about how something is flagged.

Comment: I think the issue is, not everyone agrees with the site's definition of what is NAA or low qual.

Answer (score -10):

Just my two cents, but I think this answer is VLQ rather than NAA. My reasoning is purely down to semantics:

NAA would be something like "You should really be using Sass for your CSS." Basically, it doesn't answer the question *at all.*

VLQ would be your typical *Look it up yourself/Google it/Here's the very least amount of information I'll give you* answer.

In some ways, this answer really blurs the line so I can see why you'd question it! Anyway, I hope this at the very least shares a different perspective on the matter.

Comment: Your "NAA" example would have an "NAA" flag declined. "NAA" applies to answers that are in no way trying to answer the question. Stuff like "Thanks", "I'm having this problem, too!", requests for clarification, or other posts not related to the question at all.

Comment: @Cerbrus surely my example wouldn't be declined as it is in no way answering the question, right? Suggesting an alternative tool which in no way solves the issue of the question isn't any more of an answer than "Apples could be red or green" A true statement, but a statement rather than a constructive answer. I'd love more clarification on the whole vetting process, myself :)

Comment: Feel free to try it. In my experience, "NAA" _often_ gets declined because the flagged answer is in _some_ way an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus which is why people cries [foul!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286270/792066) when their NAA's are declined... because it does not follow logic.

Comment: @Braiam: _"because it does not follow logic"_ -- says who? The people who don't comprehend the logic? I think the guidance for NAA is very clear: _any_ good faith attempt to _answer_ the question cannot be considered NAA. That still leaves plenty of room for flagging NAA: the most common example is when people leave answers that should be comments. There's also spam, follow-up questions to the original question, etc. That a post doesn't _successfully_ or _usefully_ answer the question does not preclude the post from being an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The usual reason for declining I've heard is that it's an attempt to answer **a** question, not **the** question specifically. Phrased accordingly, it's easier to understand.

Comment: @PeterDuniho flaggers have more context and knowledge to recognize a answer that doesn't attempt to answer a question, moderators [deliberately](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290141/792066) [ignore the context around the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag#comment156539_286270)